# TinyButStrong magnet tag shows in output docx

Tags: docx, opentbs

Hi my colleague and I has been trying to get the TinyButStrong plugin openTBS to create some docx files. 
We have a live system which creates some RTF files, with data from MySQL. We want to change this to docx, use openTBS. A couple of super users then in Word manage the templates.

We have a problem with creating the files, as we need to remove a line, if data isn't present. 
If we in the Word template do

```
<w:p>[*fieldname*;magnet=w:p]*some kind of text*</w:p>
```

it hiddes the line if fieldname contains no data, and if if contains data, it will show the line. GREAT :-)

The problem is, that it also shows `<w:p>` and `</w:p>` when it contains data, and we don't like that.

How do we get it to stop showing these tags?

Answer (score 0):

The TBS parameter `ope=minv` is done for thus purpose: it performs the magnet behavior but keep the field invisible (`minv` stands for *magnet invisible*).

So the solution is:

```
<w:p>[*fieldname*;magnet=tbs:p;ope=minv]*some kind of text*</w:p>
```

By the way, `magnet=tbs:p` is better than `magnet=w:p` because your template stays compatible when converted to another other format (LibreOffice).

Comment: I have now changed it to 
<w:p>[onshow.r477;magnet=tbs:p;ope=minv] ekskl. Moms2: [onshow.r505a] [onshow.r525] </w:p>
but it still shows <w:p>

Comment: What are the `<w:p>` in your template ? is that text that you can read in your template when you edit it with Ms Word, or does it means the invisible inner XML ?

Comment: <w:p> is the surrounding tag, that should control if a line should be shown or not. We have taken it from some documentation on the web.

But yes, we have typed it in the Word template, and can see it in there.
Maybe that is the problem, it's not working as a inner XML ,but if so how do we do that?

Comment: Yes, your usage can bring confusion and will probably not work as you expect. The tage `<w:p>` is used by Ms Word in order to delimitate  a paragraph in the inner XML stored in the DOCX. But when you type the same string in your document using Ms Word, a different string is stored in the XML. The stored string for `<w:p>` is `&lt;w:p&gt;`. OpenTBS can find and manipulate the inner XML entities, but not the one you've typed. It seems to me that your `<w:p>` tags are simply useless, I think you can omit them.

Comment: Well we found somewhere an example showing it with <w:p> and </w:p>, and we just copied it and tried to refit it to our needs. But we much worked on a corrupt document, because we tried it on a another docx and now it works as expected. We could even remove the <w:p> and </w:p> tags.